# How do I detect when the sound has finished playing when using PlaySound in Win32 SDK?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, playsound

I am using the `PlaySound` function from the Win32 SDK to play a wave sound file. Currently, I have the following line of code:

```
PlaySound(szFile,NULL,SND_FILENAME );
```

But now I want to know, how I can detect the time when the wave file finished playing? I want to change a button's text when the wave stops playing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PlaySound is very limited in what it can do.  In a product I work on, we built a media playback library on top of DirectSound to do get over the limitations.  Among many things it did, it involved writing a WAV file parser and threading code to maintain a stream of PCM samples into a DirectSound buffer.  Not for the faint of heart.

You could go this route, but here's some simpler suggestions.

1. If you know the length of the WAV file you are playing, you can call PlaySound with the SND_ASYNC flag.  Schedule a timer to fire at the estimated time the sound is supposed to finish playing.  If you don't know the length of the WAV file, you could write a parser to read the header of the file.  Compares the sampling rate and format from the "fmt" chunk to the number of bytes in the data chunk to compute the time length of the file.
2. OR.... Create a dedicated thread for issuing PlaySound calls (without the SND_ASYNC flag).  When the synchronous PlaySound function returns, do a PostMessage to your UI thread to update the button. If you have overlapping calls to PlaySound, you'll likely need to do some multi-threaded synchronization, but it shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Why does this need to happen on a second thread?

Comment: @Cody.  I don't know the asker's scenario, but I'm presuming he doesn't want to block his UI thread if his sound is sufficiently long.  Otherwise his UI will appear frozen and unresponsive while the sound plays. He could use SND_ASYNC, but he wouldn't have anyway of knowing when the sounds has finished playing.

Comment: Yeah, that's certainly reasonable. I didn't consider that the sound file was very long, and the question didn't give very much detail to make me think otherwise.

Comment: @selbie : dedicated thread : one issue I can see is you loose possibility to stop sound.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specify the `SND_ASYNC` flag, the [`PlaySound` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743680.aspx) is **synchronous**, meaning that after you call it, it does not return control to your program until *after* it has finished playing the sound file.

Therefore, once the function returns a value (either `TRUE` if successful, or `FALSE` otherwise), you know that the sound has finished playing.

You can simply update the text of your button control in the next line of code, immediately after you call the `PlaySound` function. If you want to ensure that the button gets updated immediately to reflect your changes, you might need to call the [`UpdateWindow` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145167.aspx), as well.

Comment: using `SND_ASYNC` can still not get the stop playing timepoint of  the wave file.

Comment: @tunpishuang: Yeah. I said **not** to use `SND_ASYNC`.

Comment: if using `SND_SYNC` and the wave file is pretty long , user have to wait till the end of the playing , but cannot interrupt the playing, because the windows message loop doesn't run and wait for the end of the playing. that is a also not good for the program.

Comment: @tunpishuang: Information like that should have been in your question. If you are wanting to play a *long* sound file, I think that merits specific mention. Don't force us to guess at the details.

Comment: sorry for i cannot explan my question well, because of the poor english. xD    thx anyway.