# C++ Determine If A Sound Is Done Playing

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, audio

For my program, I want to play a theme song. How can I know when it's done playing so then I could just call the song to play again? Here is my code to play the sound:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <Windows.h>\

    #pragma comment (lib , "winmm.lib") // Used for sound

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {

        PlaySound(TEXT("Background Music.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME|SND_ASYNC);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: If your goal is to continuously play the one sound, why not pas [SND_LOOP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in to `PlaySound`

Comment: similar question is already asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934059/how-do-i-detect-when-the-sound-has-finished-playing-when-using-playsound-in-win3)

Answer (score 2):

The solution to my program is just to add in SND_LOOP.

Comment: This may solve your immediate problem, but does not answer the question you asked.